# What is the difference between пытаться и пробовать?

Tags: словоупотребление

It seems that whenever I use one, I'm told to use the other :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of these words may be used in sense of trying something, making attempts to do something. Although, word `пытаться` emphasizes that this process is difficult to a person involved.

*Я **попытаюсь** научиться танцевать танго.* - *I'll try to learn how to dance tango.*

`Пробовать`, when used as "to try something" means that a person doesn't make a big effort to achieve result, just "tastes" a new action. This is because the other meaning of the word "пробовать" is actually "to taste something".

*Я **попробую** сходить на занятие по танцам.* - *I'm going to try dance classes*

Answer (score 5):

**Пытаться-попытаться** means "to make an effort to do something if you are not sure of the result":

Я попытаюсь устроиться на работу, **но не уверен, что мне удастся.**

The synonym of пытаться-попытаться is **стараться-постараться**.

**Пробовать-попробовать** means "to try", "to taste" or "to test"  It doesn't have the meaning of making a big effort.

Я попробую устроиться на работу.

Я хочу попробовать шоколад.

Учёные пробуют новый прибор в действии.

Answer (score 4):

- Пытатся - To make an attempt
- Пробовать - To sample something (try a new dish), also to make an
  attempt.