# What is the difference between пытаться and стараться?

Tags: выбор-слова

I am trying to understand the difference between the words "пытаться" and "стараться".

According to the dictionaries that are available both mean "try" or "attempt" something, but in slightly different senses, which I am unable to work out.

[This answer](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/6711/5929) to a related question claims that the words are synonymous. But it doesn't seem like that according to my dictionaries.

[This question](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/9121/5929) seem to be a duplicate of mine, but it is in Russian and I am yet not proficient enough to understand it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is my attempt at translation of the accepted answer to the duplicate (your second link):

> (limiting the scope to similar meanings only)
>
> **пытаться** - (*try*) to perform directed actions in hopes to obtain result.
>
> **пробовать** - to try, while being unsure in usefulness of the chosen approach
>
> **стараться** - while sticking to the chosen approach, expend the efforts to obtain the best result.

The difference between your words is the same as between the nouns **попытка** and **старание**.  A more suitable translation for the latter that I could find is '*assiduity*' (the former is, of course, '*attempt*').

Hence you can translate "**пытаться**" as "*to try, to attempt*" and "**стараться**" as "*to apply oneself, to strive, to exert oneself*"

http://en.glosbe.com/ru/en/ seems to have those.

---

Examples:

> Я **пытаюсь** придумать примеры. - I am *trying* to come up with examples.
>   Он **старается** выглядеть счастливым. - He *strives* to look happy.
>   Она всячески **старалась** не показать вида. - She *endeavored* at all cost not to show it.
>   Вчера мы **пытались** доказать это. - Yesterday we *attempted* to prove it.
>   Я **стараюсь** не подводить друзей. - I *take pains* not to fail my friends.

Comment: I applied myself :-)

Comment: [The answer](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/6709/what-is-the-difference-between-%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C/6711#6711) I linked to have this description of "пробовать": "to try", "to taste" or "to test". "Try a new dish" is given as an example in another answer. That is not really the same as the explanation given here.

Comment: Yes, two explanations do differ.  But you weren't asking about "пробовать".

Comment: "пытаться" is"to try to do x" (no special meaning attached). "стараться" is "to try your best to do x" (with effort; to remember something etc). "пробовать" is for the most part the physical "to try" to try some ice cream, to try a new style. The first two do not have an object after the verb; they will be followed by another verb. the last one can be followed by an object in the accusative.

Comment: An example using both words in the same sentence to illustrate the difference between the desired result (пытался переубедить) and the method of operation for doing it effectively (старался не обидеть): 

Я пытался его переубедить, поэтому старался избегать болезненных для него тем.
I wanted him to change his mind, so I tried to only use the words that wouldn't cause any offence (to make it easy for him to agree).

Comment: Lets accept this. It would however be easier to understand and an even better answer with some examples!